# RSpec thinks created file is empty

Tags: ruby, rspec

I've created a class that creates a new text file. When I try to compare it with an existing file it seems that RSpec thinks the created file is empty.

`expect(open @expected).to eq(open @result)`

The result:

```
(compared using ==)

   Diff:
   @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
   -[]
   +["The expected output\n"]
```

Here's the code that creates the file:

```
FileUtils.touch out_path
target = File.new out_path, 'w+'

File.open(in_path, "r") do |file_handle|
  file_handle.each_line do |line|
    target.puts line
  end
end
```

Comment: Show us the code that creates a file.

Comment: Added, the file is definitely created and has the correct content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not flush the file content to disk. Ruby will flush it itself, but whenever it decides to. To assure that the file content is flushed, one should use the block variant with `File#open` instead of `File.new`:

```
File.open(out_path, 'w+') do |target|
  File.open(in_path, "r") do |file_handle|
    file_handle.each_line do |line|
      target.puts line
    end
  end
end # here file is flushed
```

With `File#new` you have an option to [`flush`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html#method-i-flush) the content explicitly or do implicitly by calling [`close`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html#method-i-close).

Hope it helps.